# RoR save body of rest put to file system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have used Ruby on Rails to create a simple Rest api server.  I have added to my route.rb this, which sends the whole path to myapp's controller's update method, which I need:

```
put 'dreceiver/*other', to: 'myapps#update'
```

My controller:

```
class MyAppsController < ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  # PUT 
  # Expected Parameters: {"other"=>"api/1.0/file/abc123"}
  def update
    #Need to grab last part of path sent in:
    if params[:other] =~ /api\/1.0\/file\/.*/
      batchid = params[:other].split('/').last
    else
      batchid = nil
    end

    unless batchid.nil?
      render :text => '', :status => 201
    else
     render :text => '', :status => 401
    end

    return
  end
end
```

My problem:  I expect a gzip file to be sent in the body of the PUT request.  I need to save it to the file system.  I see lot's of examples of storing it in the db using paperclip, but I really don't want to do any migrations or deal with the db if I don't have to... this is just to test some client code sending the file.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I was looking for request.raw_post.  Once I got that, I just saved it to a file using File.open.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip does not store uploaded files in the database, it stores them on the filesystem and then writes the filename to the database (usually -- it can be configured in multiple ways).

Multipart POSTs (and PUTs or PATCHes) work just like regular POSTs. Rails will automatically create a Hash-like object from the request body. One of the values in this hash should be a object that responds to `#tempfile` that you can treat pretty much just like a normal `File` object.

```
def update
  gzip_file = params[:uploaded_file].tempfile # replace uploaded_file with the field name
  ...
end
```